# Can I shorten this if statement?

Tags: c++

This `if`-statement currently compares a variable with a static number and if they are equal, it gives the `settime7` variable a hexidecimal that it uses to send time to a unit.

Is there a way to shorten this `if`-statement:

```
if(timeM == 0){
   settime7 = 0x00;
}
else if(timeM == 1){
   settime7 = 0x01;
}
else if(timeM == 2){
   settime7 = 0x02;
}
else if(timeM == 3){
   settime7 = 0x03;
}
// ...and so on to timeM == 60 and settime = 0x3C.
```

Comment: `settime7 = timeM;`?

Comment: cant do that timeM is a decimal i need a hexidecimal for settime

Comment: Well, that sorts it a little bit.... loelol

Comment: A number is a number is a number. `1` and `0x01` are the same number. You don't store hex or decimal, both are only different a way to designate the same *number*.

Comment: You don't understand how integer work, there is no concept of decimal or hexadecimal. Just number. The same number assigned from decimal or hexadecimal is the same number. There are both `int`.

Comment: you are right its working @MatthieuBrucher if you display it as answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just assign the variable:

```
settime7 = timeM;
```

Whether you write yourself the integer as decimal or hexadecimal doesn't matter for a stored integer.

Comment: This worked perfectly instead of an if statement of 60 different ifs its now decrease to 1 sentence

Answer (score 4):

if I well understand you want

```
...
else if(timeM == 60){
   settime7 = 0x60;
}
```

then :

```
settime7 = (timeM / 10) * 16 + (timeM % 10)
```

Comment: @AsierAranbarri I just try to understand his need

Comment: @bruno You should not "try" to understand OP. If the question is not clear, ask clarifications in comments, do not write a "try" answer.

Comment: This might actually be the answer. Assuming the OP ever bothers returning and explaining if `60` should indeed be mapped to `0x60`

Comment: (i didnt downvote). The thing is, he already has the number, you are just converting it in another number. The representation differs, not the value

Comment: @Holt I am not a robot, I am a human, all is not black or white, the gray is allowed :-)

Comment: Upvoted for merit. This is a valid interpretation of `// ...and so on to 60.`

Comment: This answer makes sense. More of an explanation would be useful, so other people can understand